# Webserver insists on opening "blog1.php" instead of "index.php"

Tags: php, htaccess, cpanel

I'm at my wits' end.

I have just ripped out a website and in the process of rebuilding everything.

Previously, the 'home page' of the website is a blog, with the address "www.mydomain.com/blog1.php".

After exporting everything, I deleted the whole directory, and -- based on request -- immediately create a `blog/` directory. The idea is to get the blog back up as soon as possible, and temporarily redirect people accessing `www.mydomain.com` to the blog.

Accessing the blog via `http://www.mydomain.com/blog/` works. So I put in an index.php file containing a (temporary) redirect to the blog's address.

The problem: The server *insists* on opening `blog1.php` instead of `index.php`. Even after we deleted all the files (including `.htaccess`). And even putting in a new `.htaccess` file with the single line of `DirectoryIndex index.php` doesn't work. The server stubbornly wants `blog1.php`.

Now, the server is actually a webhosting, so I have no actual access to it. I have to do my work via cPanel.

Currently, I work around this issue by creating `blog1.php`; but I really want to know why the server does not revert to opening `index.php`. Did I perhaps miss some important settings in the byzantine cPanel menu page?

Answer (score 2):

Try contacting them and asking them to restart the Apache service.
I had a similar issue long back with shared hosting. I had to get them to restart the Apache web service. Something cached in the memory.

Comment: Makes sense, although since it's a webhosting, I'm not sure they will do it. But thanks, anyway! Won't hurt to try :-)